# Coredata: Multiple xcdatamodeld files in the same iOS project?

Tags: ios, core-data

Is it possible to serve two xcdatamodeld core data in the same project and load each according to a conditional?

I have `BTPModel.xcdatamodeld` and `FTModel.xcdatamodeld`

According to the comments this line below does this:

```
NSManagedObjectModel model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
```

> // looks up all models in the specified bundles and merges them; if
>   nil is specified as argument, uses the main bundle

Can I do something like this? (pseudo code)

```
if (config == @"FT") {
   model = [NSManagedObjectModel load:@"FTModel.xcdatamodeld"];  
} else {
   model = [NSManagedObjectModel load:@"BPTModel.xcdatamodeld"];  
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have now tried this

```
        NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"F11iModel" withExtension:@"xcdatamodeld"];
```

Without any luck. url remains null.

**UPDATE**
Extension is momd. Now it works!

```
        NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"F11iModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

Comment: Have you tried? I don't see any reason you couldn't.

Comment: If you intend on using both models for the same user you will need to have separate store files as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Just a few things to pay attention to:

The loading of a specific model is not done with some `load` method, but with `initWithContentsOfURL`. You get the URL with the main bundle's  `URLForResource`. You can pass different resource names to this according to the configuration information.

I would recommend that you also use different persistent stores to make sure there is no attempt to open a the store with the wrong model (which will crash your app).

Comment: Thanks Mundi, I do have two different persistent stores. That would be no problem.  What remains a problem is how to find out the path to the model?  `model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"BPTModel.xcdatamodeld"]];` This doesn't work.

Comment: As stated, you have to use `urlForResource` not `urlWithString`.

Comment: My bad, you are right. Please check my question for the update. It is still not clear. Thanks